# Why don't using new operator for creation dependecy in Angular?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

When we use `constructor(private dep: Dep) {}` syntax, we get advantages like easy debugging/testing and our consumer does not get highly coupled with dependency.

If we need to change name of our dep from `Dep` to `NewDep`, we need to change this name everywhere it is used.

But if we using DI pattern it works same or not? We need to change `constructor(private dep: Dep) {}` to `constructor(private dep: NewDep) {}`.

Why we get coupled without using DI pattern for create and inject dependencies?

Comment: DI isn't about making name refactors easier. Any half decent IDE can handle that task just fine. It's about when nested dependencies need to change and keeping track of stateful dependencies.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! For software design patterns, please see [softwareengineering.se]

Answer (score -3):

In angular, the services should be singleton which means that the instance of the services should be reuse. we can inject that instance using the DI.  we can provide the data in root level or module level. Best way to is using-->
`enter code here`
 @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

Comment: Services in angular should only be singleton if they’re suited to being singleton. Plenty of services are not suited to being singletons. This is 100% wrong. Angular allows component providers for a reason.